# Should I need to create a separate page for each button in php?

Tags: php

I am working on a project and it contains a button "buy now" for each item. Should I need to create a new php page for each button when the user clicks it?
Is there any better way of doing this?

If possible explain with small code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create new page for display button, you can simply send item id through get or method on next/cart page 
eg `<a href="http://example.com/cart.php?itemId=<YourItemid>">buy now</a>`